# Doing sum's if certain conditions are true

Tags: mysql

I am trying to build a query that does a sum if a certain parameter is 
set. For example:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(<condition>,field,field)) AS total_value
```

...which is working correctly.

But i have **more than one condition in the IF()**, like:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(<condition> <condition>,field,field)) AS total_value
```

..which is not working, could you have any idea what should be the right query for this.

**Update**

Sorry for wrong queries, right queries are

My current query looks something like this: 
SELECT SUM(IF(condition1,field,field)) AS total_value
which is working correctly.

But i have more than one condition in IF(),like
SELECT SUM(IF(condition1 condition2,field,field)) AS total_value
which is not working, could you have any idea what should be the right query for this.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  You can edit your question (and answers) by clicking the edit link - it's on the left side, across from your username & gravatar.  There's also syntax called MarkDown, that will let you tweak the formatting to make things easier to read.

Answer (score 10):

Look at the Case statement:

```
Select Sum( Case When column = test Then column2 Else column3 End )
...
```

If you have multiple conditions, you can still use case:

```
Select Sum( Case 
            When column1 = 'Foo' Then column2 
            When column1 = 'Bar' Then column3
            When column1 = 'Gamma' Then column2 + column3
            Else column3 End )
From ...
```

In this scenario, if column1 is not null and does not equal 'Foo', then it will go to the next When statement. If that test is not true, it goes to the next and so on.

Answer (score 2):

```
select sum(case when a = b and x = y then field1 + field2 else 0 end)
```

**Update:**

Perhaps you mean this:

```
select sum(case when a = b then field1 else field2 end)
```

Comment: @Gugu: Can you please update your question to include example data and expected output, so it's more clear to us what you're after?

Comment: @Gugu: Post the exact statement you are running, along with your schema, anf explain **how** it's not working. Also, see my update.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(IF(field = value1 OR field = value2 OR field = value3,1,NULL)) AS total_value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(IF(<condition1>, 
              IF(<condition2>,
                 <field1>,
                 <field2>),
              <field2>)) AS total_value
```

Comment: You should update your original question to clarify exactly what it is you are looking to get.